# How to load new flows in runtime node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I want every time node red page reload, depending on the user (session user I created myself) to show that user's stream. Each user's stream will be fetched from another server via http protocol. Where can I put the code to get the new flows file in the source code Node Red

Comment: Given this and your last question I suggest you post to the Node-RED forum or on the Node-RED Slack and explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to achieve and we can tell you if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Node-RED is currently NOT multi-tenant multi-user.

Any given instance of Node-RED can only run one flow at a time, even you you define multiple users they will all work on the SAME flow.

If you want to support multiple users with their own flows, they need run separate instances and each instance will need a distinct hostname (currently authentication tokens are kept in browser local storage which is host scoped so there is no way to run multiple instances on different paths on the same host)

If you want to push a new flow to a given instance then the [Admin API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/) has HTTP REST endpoints that support this, but any new flow you push will replace the existing one.